# Windows hidden directories not recognized by Java

Tags: java

On my windows 10 machine when I check for hidden folders, Files.isHidden always returns false.

C:\ProgramData is generally a hidden folder but the program returns false instead of expected true

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Path directory = Path.of("C:\\ProgramData").toAbsolutePath().normalize();
    System.out.println(Files.isHidden(directory));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have probably hit a [bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8215467). JDK 13 has been patched with a fix.
Use the recommendations in the fix note

eg.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Path directory = Path.of("C:\\ProgramData").toAbsolutePath().normalize();
    DosFileAttributes dosFileAttributes = Files.readAttributes(directory, DosFileAttributes.class);
    System.out.println(Files.isHidden(directory));    // Returns true for > JDK13
    System.out.println(dosFileAttributes.isHidden()); // Returns true for < JDK13
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Dhrubajyoti. <-- Even this tagging doesnt work for me :P